# Autocompletion Plugin for vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion

In recent days I use a lot of vimscript and it would be helpful to have some autocompletion.

Like when I write `jo` the autocompletion would recommend me to write `join`.

I have installed YouCompleteMe, but its hard to search in the internet for vimscript autocompletion because of the ambiguity.

Comment: I recommand : https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim, There is autocompletion for vimscript :)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you asking for. YouCompleteMe does autocomplete vimscript key words. Are you asking for autocomplete plugin written entirely in vimscript?

Also I believe that vimscript autocompletion is builtin in the omnicompletion.

Comment: maybe it is not clear, i want something that gives me all the vimscript functions like when I write somethin in vimscript, it autocompletes like the internal join function or *bpre* and it suggests bprevious like i have when i write an ex-command.

Somethink like   autocmd FileType vim set omnifunc=????????

Comment: But that's exactly what YCM does: https://asciinema.org/a/1c2gyfpft51rnoptt86bjvvwr

This is youcompleteme running in vim 7.3.

You stated that you have YCM installed. Are you not happy with it and looking for something else or does it not work for you?

Comment: You can search in vim-scripts.org . I have seen vimscript autocompletion plugin there

Comment: @dkns Vimscript completion does not appear to be a built-in feature of YCM. What's the result of `:set omnifunc?` in your setup where this works?

Answer (score 4):

The OP's question is whether there is a good omnifunc for Vimscript itself, such as offering semantically or syntactically are completion suggestions for vimscript functions, variables, etc. A number of answers just note general autocompletion plugins like YCM and snippet plugins like UltiSnips.

So to answer the original question: Yes, there's vim-verdin: https://github.com/machakann/vim-Verdin. It's surprisingly good at vimscript suggestions, and seems to be getting better.

But be warned though that at the time of writing it doesn't work perfectly with YCM (I would know as the YCM maintainer!). It works well enough that I use it regularly however. Disabling `g:verdin#autocomplete` and enabling `g:verdin#cooperativemode` allows you to hit ctrl-space for completion suggestions from verdin.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Vimscript, so this might not matter at all, but the documentation for Verdin uses `g:Verdin#autocomplete` (upper-case V instead of lower-case). Also, in case anyone else wonders about auto-triggering: The semantic triggers need to be manually defined through `let g:ycm_semantic_triggers`. I used `'vim': ['#', ':']`, which seems to work fine. Manual triggering with ctrl-space works anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Vim actually has a native autocomplete engine. It's not as fully featured as neocomplete or YCM, but it's fast and usually gets the job done. You can find out more about it with `:h i_ctrl-x`.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) and [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). There are others that I haven't tried like [youcompleteme](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) and [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) that may help. This last one ([ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)) looks very nice. Check the image.

[image]

One last sugggestion, for [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) don't forget to install the '[honza/vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets)' plugin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OP mentioned that he already tried YCM. You mentioned ultisnips which isn't an autocompletion plugin but snippets plugin which contains like 3 vimscript related snippets.